# Enabling TCP md5 signature option in centOS?

Tags: centos, iptables, tcp, network-monitoring

I'm trying to enable md5 checksum/signature for tcp packets in centOS (the main use case to stop tcp RST attacks, etc). It seems like I may be able to do this for individual ports using netcat or via iptables. What is the preferred way of enabling this option and is there a better method than those I listed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable TCP MD5 signatures on Linux you must

- Build a kernel with `CONFIG_TCP_MD5SIG` enabled
  (Per an answer on Stack Overflow you can check this by [checking the contents of `/proc/config.gz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621755/259612))
- Write programs which set the appropriate socket options to enable them
  (Per the Stack Overflow folks the correct option to set is [`TCP_MD5SIG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139298/259612)).